# installing npm in mac with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using mac. So, I used this command 

`$ brew node`

and it did install node

`$ node -v
v7.6.0`

but when I print this command I got this error:

`$ npm -v
-bash: npm: command not found`

What is wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749549/npm-command-not-found-after-installing-node

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3125