# npm 'command not found' no matter what I try

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

On MacOS:

I'm unable to execute any npm package command. Every time I try, I see command not found. Like so:

```
-bash: live-server: command not found
```

I've installed node.js directly from the website. 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

I've installed live-server globally, and locally. It appears to work. When I try the command, it fails.

I've removed node.js and npm, re-installed and still fail to execute a command. I'm quite stumped. I've reviewed similar posts, implemented the suggested solutions and still can't manage to execute any npm command. 
Several of the posts I've reviewed: 
[sudo: npm: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found)

[NPM Command Not Found After Installing Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32749549/npm-command-not-found-after-installing-node/35711408)

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? 
Did you check if NPM is in Path on "Environments variable"

Comment: I'm using MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

My bash_profile file had the wrong data saved. Correcting the file solved the problem.